# If $f(x) = x^4 - x^2 + 1$, find the values of $x$ such that $f(f(f(x))) \le x^8$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

> If $$f(x) = x^4 - x^2 + 1$$ find the values of $x$ such that $f(f(f(x))) \le x^8$

I noticed that $f(\pm 1) = 1 \implies \underbrace{f(f(f(... f(\pm 1)..)))}_{\text{n times}} = 1$. thus, $f(f(f(x))) = x^8$ at $x = \pm 1$. Fortunately, these were the only two solutions to this problem. However, this is hacky at best and incomplete at worst.

Can somebody provide a rigorous proof for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f(x)$=$x^2(x^2+1/x^2-1)$ ,

Now notice that

$(x^2+1/x^2-1)\ge1$ for all real x . (Apply $AM \ge GM$ for $x^2$ and $1\over x^2$)

That is $f(x)\ge x^2$ , which implies that $f(f(f(x))) \ge x^8$

But in the question it is given that $f(f(f(x))) \le x^8$

Therefore , $f(f(f(x))) = x^8$ , which will happen when $(x^2+1/x^2-1)=1$ , hence $x = \pm 1$ are the only solutions.